# Increase update rate of "problems" bar in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make VSCode update typos and detected problems instantly? I noticed that it usually takes VSCode about 1-2 seconds to update the problems status bar and the red underline. Even after fixing the error VSCode usually takes a couple seconds to update.

Is there any way to change this specific setting in the settings.json file to something like 0ms or at least make it a little quicker or do you know of an extension that could take care of this?

I am specifically asking about C++ code because that is the main language I am currently writing in.

**UPDATE:** For anyone wondering, I actually managed to find what I was looking for. I disabled the Microsoft C++ plugins and extensions for VSCode and I am now instead using the clangd extension for C++ which instantly shows you problems and possible compile errors.

Comment: ***Is there a way to make VSCode update typos and detected problems instantly?*** I expect the performance is a function of your computer speed and not an intentional delay. Remember that Intellisense is a fast partial compiler and it has to compile your code as you type.

Comment: C++ is a complex language, you should revel in the fact that you can see the results of your changes in just a few seconds, it's quite an achievement

Comment: @drescherjm Computer performance shouldn't be the problem unless VSCode isn't able to fully utilize the newer Apple chips.

Comment: @AlanBirtles In comparison to Sublime Text which does it instantly VSCode does seem to be a little too slow with handling problems

Comment: @user I was solely referring to mistakes that cause compiler errors. The C_Cpp.workspaceParsingPriority were already set at highest.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: please don't put solutions in the question post. put your solution in an answer post. I'd also encourage you to label it explicitly as a workaround, since it's not _exactly_ what your question post is actually asking for..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is possible to reduce the time from the settings.
But I have noticed a quicker file update when you save your file, it might help if you didn't know.